# puppet stdlib 'member" function not working

Tags: ruby, puppet

Trying to use the member function of the puppet stdlib module:

effectively:

```
$myvariable = 'FOO'
```

then when using the member function:

```
member(['FOO','BAR'], $myvariable)
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Function 'member' must be the value of a statement at /etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/manifests/init.pp:###
```

Comment: @MattSchuchard explains the error message in his answer, but I can't help thinking that the error must be a symptom of a different problem.  After all, what sense would it make to call the `member()` function and ignore the result?  This sort of thing is one of the reasons that we tend to request a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the stdlib documentation for member, we see that member is an rvalue. This means in this context that you need to have its output assigned. This is what the error message of `must be the value of a statement` is hinting at. Note a helpful wikipedia article on l-values and r-values https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue.

Your code will work, for example, if you assign the output of `member(['FOO','BAR'], $myvariable)` to a variable or a resource attribute.

For example:

```
$myvariable = 'FOO'
$variable = member(['FOO','BAR'], $myvariable)
notify { $variable: }
```

will result in a notify 'true' during compilation.

Comment: Thanks this really helps a lot!